# Expanding LVM Root Partition

Tags: partitioning, lvm

When I installed this machine, it was on a 120gb SSD. Now I've moved it over to a 256gb SSD and am wasting a ton of space:

```
# lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
├─sda1                  8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                  8:2    0   488M  0 part /boot
└─sda3                  8:3    0 118.3G  0 part
  ├─alonso--vg-root   252:0    0  86.3G  0 lvm  /
  └─alonso--vg-swap_1 252:1    0    32G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

How can I actually expand sda3 and then lvextend root to take advantage of the new space without just wiping out the disk and starting over?

Comment: https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/extending-lvm or see lvm documentation

Comment: I'd rather actually expand the partition than just add another partition on the same disk to the group.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98339/how-do-i-extend-a-partition-with-a-lvm-and-the-contained-physical-volume-and-log

Comment: Worked for me. Even though deleting and re-creating my root partition with fdisk is terrifying.